# Setting background color of checkboxes in materialize using CSS variables

Tags: html, css, materialize

I use materialize CSS and generate checkboxes dynamically. I want different checkboxes to have different colors.
When I'm trying to set the color inline, it doesn't take effect:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in checkbox-custom" style="background-color: red;" />
```

What does work, is setting the following style in my .css file like so:

```
.checkbox-custom[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But this way, I can't set up a color dynamically per each individual checkbox, and I have many colors, so creating a class per each color is not an option.

I tried using css variables in the following manner,
in my .css file:

```
:root {
  --checkbox-color: grey;
}

.checkbox-custom[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked+span:not(.lever):after {
  background-color: var(--checkbox-color);
}
```

And creating the checkbox dynamically in JS as inner html using

```
container.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in checkbox-custom" style="--checkbox-color: ' + myJSColorVar + ';" />';
```

But the checkbox stays grey and the variable I pass is ignored.

Is there a way to set the checkbox color dynamically from inline CSS without setting a custom class per each color?
I've reviewed the following questions which helped me getting started
[How to pass parameters to css classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893823/how-to-pass-parameters-to-css-classes),
[Change color of checkbox in Materialize framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261021/change-color-of-checkbox-in-materialize-framework)
but still weren't able to combine the two concepts.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how css inheritance works. Your custom property is not going to apply to any selector that contains this element, only to child elements. And a input doesn't have children so you don't see it having an effect. Set it to the wrapper element instead.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @cloned thanks, this indeed was the issue! going to post an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

As [@cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4733161/cloned) pointed out, setting the variable on a parent element helped.
specifically, what I did is:

```js
const myColors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

myColors.forEach(color => {
  const label = document.createElement("label");
  label.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in checkbox-custom"/><span class="checkbox-span"></span>';

  label.style.setProperty("--checkbox-color", color);

  document.body.appendChild(label);
});
```

```css
.checkbox-custom[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked+span:not(.lever):after {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background-color: var(--checkbox-color);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
```